# How to put background image React?

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

I need your help. I am trying to set background image for my header. Photo is in the "public" folder. I prescribe the way to my photo in css. But i have a mistake. What i am doing wrong? How to set the background image in React?

Css

```
.header{
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
background-image: url(./public/one.jpg);
}
```

Js

```
import React from "react";

export let Header = () => {
return <header className='header'>
</header>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping `background-image: url("/public/one.jpg");` instead?

Comment: is that JS in the src folder?

Comment: @AreebKhan Yes, i tried it. When I try your option it shows me an error all the way. When I write background-image: url("./public/one.jpg"); 
emphasizes me only under the photo, although the name and extension of the photo are correct

Comment: @DavidGrosh The photo is in the "public" folder

Comment: where is the JS located? not the photo.

Comment: @DmitryChernyak Oh for some reason I assumed you created a `public` folder inside the `public` folder. Try `background-image: url("/one.jpg");`

Comment: @DavidGrosh The Header component is located in the "Header" folder located in the "src" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're in the src folder, so you'll need to go to the parent directory in order to get to the public folder, like this: `"../public/one.jpg"` instead of `"./public/one.jpg"`.

I would recommend to add an asset folder within src, instead of using the public folder.

Comment: Crosh Thanks, it helped me. The last question is, is there a difference that saves the photo? Is it in the "public" folder or in the "src" folder?

Comment: it's more recommended to use the src folder, for this use case. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/